# Cannot edit the values of Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have fetched the data from the database, but I need to make changes to that collection or arrays of collection. Whenever I made changes; these remain limited to the scope of function, so, when the function called again that collection reset to their previous values.

Is there any way to change/edit the laravel collection (the root instance without copying the data like with map(), each())?

Comment: Share the code here

Answer (score 1):

To modify the original Collection, you'll want to use [`transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-transform).

From the docs:

> Unlike most other collection methods, transform modifies the collection itself. If you wish to create a new collection instead, use the map method

In most cases I find that `map` or `each` is really the appropriate method, but I find this method is especially useful when needing to modify paginated results from a query.